# Migration not skipping a row

Tags: 7, migrations

I have a talent for finding the hard issues.  I have a custom migration class importing taxonomy terms.  The class is an in-house customization, and we have it working happily on other sites.  On my site, it is not working.  There is a chance this is related to the data, which is coming from the client and possibly not clean.  Here is my issue.  I am implementing the public function prepareRow($current_row) with the intent of skipping some rows that I know will cause trouble.  Specifically, anything with a non-numeric id value.

1. I know the function is called, I see "Gojira!" appear
2. I know the value that is causing an error
3. The function is not being respected by the system.

Here is my function:

```
public function prepareRow($current_row) {
  $safe = FALSE;
  if(is_numeric($current_row->id)){
    $safe = TRUE;
    // problem value is $current_row->id == 'n'
  }
  if(!$safe) {
    print('Gojira!'); // this is seen in the migration ui
    //die();  // this is ignored
    return FALSE; // this is ignored
  }

  // allow parent to skip a row
  if (parent::prepareRow($current_row) === FALSE) {
    return FALSE;
  }
}
```

Here is the error I see on the migration ui page:

```
Migration failed ... General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'n' for column 'sourceid1' at row 1
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The hint that solved this was in the error message:

```
for column 'sourceid1'
```

This column is in the Migration class's map table, where it tries to make a record of what it has processed.  The "fix" for this is to prevent the errant data from getting that far in the system.  I am coding a custom getItem to do the filtering for this issue there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can help.

```
    // Row object containing the specific item just imported.
    $row = $event->getRow();

    if (!$row->needsUpdate()) {
      return;
    }
```